# Update Html Table in realtime as data on Firebase RTDB changes

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

I have an HTML Table linked to a Firebase Real time database. Everything works fine except for one small issue.By using `databse.on()` instead of `database.once()`, the table does update as data is changed in the RTDB but it does not 'replace' the previously present fields in the table, it instead creates a new set of the updated values.

[image: First Initialization]

This is what it does on data update currently:

[image: On Data Update]

Heres the HTML script:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Customer table</title>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>

<body>
 <table class="table table-striped" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  var config = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyB0WrqbEu4kgR1-INNyKpAu8bfvfy0VOVc",
authDomain: "fir-freelance-fd0e6.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://fir-freelance-fd0e6-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "fir-freelance-fd0e6",
storageBucket: "fir-freelance-fd0e6.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "967741636284",
appId: "1:967741636284:web:426d2ef2112f9008945ab9"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Members');
  database.on('value', function(snapshot){
      if(snapshot.exists()){  
        var content = '';
         
          snapshot.forEach(function(data){
              var Name = data.val().Name;
              var Credit = data.val().Credit;
              content += '<tr>';
              content += '<td>' + Name + '</td>';//column1
              content += '<td>' + Credit + '</td>';//column2
              content += '</tr>';
 
         });

$('#ex-table').append(content); 

}
});
</script>
```

Ive tried changing `.append` with `.replaceWith` but that dosent work either. What im looking is just for the values that have been updated in RTDB to update in the table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this is to clear the table before adding the updated content:

```
$('#ex-table').html(content);
```

If you have many updates and/or many nodes, this may cause the HTML to flicker. If that is a problem for your app, you can [listen to the `child_` events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) instead of the whole value and perform more granular updates to the HTML based on whether the child node was added, changed, or removed.

Comment: It works but the table headers too are replaced (they disappear) as the data updates. I guess using `.html` just completely replaces everything. Any workaround for that?

Comment: NVM i just added another table under the main headers and just used the first table as the headers. That solved the problem. THANKYOU FOR YOUR HELP...!!

Comment: Add a tbody tag in the table rather than creating a completely new table to store the headers. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp